# Switching Vue to production mode

Tags: laravel, vuejs2

I'm successfully running `npm run production` on my Vue (2.6.14) application, and uploading the resultant "chunked" .js files to the public/dist/ and public/ folders on my production server.

However, when I view the site in Chrome, it tells me that I'm running Vue in development mode.

Is there a switch/variable somewhere that I'm forgetting to change?  (The APP_ENV variable in the production server's .env file is set to production.)

Thanks/Tom

Answer (score 0):

A stupid own goal.  I had

`<script type="text/javascript" src="{{  asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>`

in my app.blade.php instead of

`<script type="text/javascript" src="{{  asset('dist/app.js') }}"></script>`

and so it was reading the dev version of the app.js file (which shouldn't have been uploaded any way!)

I'll never get those hours back!